# Django data handling in custom middleware

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-middleware, django-request

In my django webapp, I have to pass user data param(udp) in a request and return the same in response without modifying it in view.

Request

```
{
        "mobile": "111111111",
        "udp":[
            { 
                "key": "keyName",
                "value":"valueName"
            },
             { 
                "key": "keyName",
                "value":"valueName"
            },
        ]
    }
```

Response

```
{
        "code": "200",
        "message": "success message",
        "response": {
            "data":"user data"
            "udp":[
                    { 
                        "key": "keyName",
                        "value":"valueName"
                    },
                     { 
                        "key": "keyName",
                        "value":"valueName"
                    }
                ]
        }
    }
```

I thought of acheiving this by writting custom middleware but after accessing request in middleware, View is throwing me error

```
you cannot access body after reading from request's data stream
```

Can anyone suggest how this can be implemented?
or
What will be best approach of doing this in django

Comment: Why are you doing this in middleware and not the view? I think accessing the body in middleware is not advised in Django.

Comment: Yes, but I need process all request for udp. That's why I wanted to make a common interface that will take care of these things.